# Where can I find out the differences between themes/styles for android?

Tags: android

I am a beginner developing apps and I am very confused by the different styles/themes. I have come into contact with the following themes so far:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar
AppTheme.NoActionBar
AppTheme.AppBarOverlay
AppTheme.PopupOverlay
```

Where can I find information on the differences on those styles, or when to use them, or where to use them?

As those seem to be default styles/themes there should be a page summarizing all those styles/themes (and all other ones), but a google search did not reveal anything useful!

Comment: This is a valid programming question, and if you don't think so, leave a comment. I will ask again and again until I have my answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170421/what-is-difference-among-styles-xml-and-themes-xml

Comment: The link does not seem to be related to my question.

Comment: okay may be my misunderstanding do you want to know when to use themes you mentioned in question?

Comment: Did you try google developer website?

Comment: I want to know e.g. what is the difference between `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and `AppTheme.NoActionBar`? Is there a special circumstance in which to use the style `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`? Why does the `activity_main.xml` Hello-World example code uses the stye `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` and not e.g. `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`? How are these styles defined? What are their differences? Where can I find their definition?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the "Applying Styles and Themes" http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles article:

The Android platform provides a large collection of styles and themes that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all available styles in the R.style class. 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/R.style.html

Comment: Your link is something I have hoped for. But still, there are many, many empty fields, definitions missing, all that 'AppCompat' seems to be something else... And do we really need hundreds of uncommented styles? What is the sense? Is anyone reading this whole page? How can a developer choose an appropriate style? This sounds crazy to me! I do not understand why this must be so cumbersome and confusing...!