# BottomNavigationView bottom background is not set to itemBackground correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have created a BottomNavigationView with 4 menus. Somehow its not setting the background color to cover the text and icon. See the screenshot, the text and image are still showing the white background

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="labelVisibilityMode">labeled</item>
    <item name="itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="itemBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/selector_bottom_bar_text</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/selector_bottom_bar_icon</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">@style/navTextActive</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">@style/navTextInactive</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/BottomNavigationView"

    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
```

[image]

1. How to fix the text and iconbackground?
2. How to add a bit of space between the icon and text?

Comment: for 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386768/how-to-change-text-padding-in-android-bottom-navigation-view

Comment: Spacing issue solved. Can you help me to fix the background

Comment: Remove `android:background` from your *theme*. Everything that doesn't have a background (most things, here the icon and label views) will use that value. This is something you don't want to have in theme. Set `android:background` on individual views or in *view styles*. [Don't mix themes and styles.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170455/2444099)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was setting the background color in theme. That caused this. After removing the background from the theme it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Eugen Pechanec. It worked. I was setting the background color in theme. That caused this. After removing the background from the theme it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bg_navigation"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bg_navigation"
```

Then create **`bg_navigation.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="hex_color_code" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="hex_color_code" />
</selector>
```

For Spacing issue, You can check [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878813/3395198) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will work. But, you can try adding this to your Activity.java file and see if it works.
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setBackgroundTintList(null);